# Reshape 2-D matrix with a specific format into a 3-D matrix (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, 2d, reshape

I have a Cartesian 2-D matrix, `A`, that contains bins of dose values in three (X,Y,Z) dimensions;

- X coordinate: from 0.0 to 50.00 cm, `nx=512` bins (9.7656E-02 cm wide)
- Y coordinate: from 0.0 to 50.00 cm, `ny=512` bins (9.7656E-02 cm wide)
- Z coordinate: from 0.0 to 27.12 cm, `nz=113` bins (2.4000E-01 cm wide)

Therefore, the total number of elements in `A` is `nx*ny*nz=29622272`. When reading a .dat-file, the data in matrix `A` are stored in the following format

> A(1,1,1) A(2,1,1) A(3,1,1) A(4,1,1) A(5,1,1) A(6,1,1) A(7,1,1) A(8,1,1) A(9,1,1) A(10,1,1)
>
> A(11,1,1) A(12,1,1) A(13,1,1) A(14,1,1) A(15,1,1) A(16,1,1) A(17,1,1) A(18,1,1) A(19,1,1) A(20,1,1)
>
> …
>
> A(503,1,1) A(504,1,1) A(505,1,1) A(506,1,1) A(507,1,1) A(508,1,1) A(509,1,1) A(510,1,1) A(511,1,1) A(512,1,1)
>
> A(1,2,1) A(2,2,1) A(3,2,1) A(4,2,1) A(5,2,1) A(6,2,1) A(7,2,1) A(8,2,1) A(9,2,1) A(10,2,1)
>
> A(11,2,1) A(12,2,1) A(13,2,1) A(14,2,1) A(15,2,1) A(16,2,1) A(17,2,1) A(18,2,1) A(19,2,1) A(20,2,1)
>
> …
>
> …
>
> A(1,1,2) A(2,1,2) A(3,1,2) A(4,1,2) A(5,1,2) A(6,1,2) A(7,1,2) A(8,1,2) A(9,1,2) A(10,1,2)
>
> …
>
> A(511,512,113) A(512,512,113)

where the first index `ix` is assigned to the X coordinate, index `iy` is assigned to the Y coordinate and index `iz` is assigned to the Z coordinate in `A(ix,iy,iz)`, and the first index runs faster than the second, and the second faster than the third. So when reading the matrix from the input file, `A` has the size `[2962228 10]` (the last row in the input file contains only two elements/columns).

I want to reshape this matrix into an equivalent Cartesian 3-D matrix, `B(ix,iy,iz)`, of dimensions `[nx ny nz] = [512 512 113]` - is there an efficient way to do this? Also, 8 extra elements are appended in the last row when reading by `fscanf()` since `A` contains 10 elements per row - how do I not include these values when reshaping?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: You say _the total number of elements in `A` is `nx*ny*nz=29622272`_ but then _A has the size `[2962228 10]`_. Can you explain this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correclty, `B = A.'; result = reshape(B(1:end-8), [512 512 113]);` may be all you need

Comment: The total number of elements that is stored in the input file is `nx*ny*nz=29622272`, but since `A` follows the mentioned format, this will leave only 2 elements along the very last row of the input file. So, when reading this file, the remaining 8 empty elements of the last row in `A` are filled in as zeroes

Comment: Aren't you discarding 8 whole columns with `reshape(B(1:end-8), [512 512 113])`?

Comment: Nope, it’s linear indexing, so it only discards the last 8 elements in linear order. Give a try and see if that’s what you need

Comment: This doesn't produce what I need. Say `A = randi([1 10], 5, 10); A(end,9:10) = 0; result = reshape(A(1:end-2), [4 4 3]);`, you won't get the correct coordinate mapping of the element values. E.g., the first 4 elements (in the first row) in `A` should correspond to the first column in `results` mapped on the first plane.

Comment: That's not the code I posted in my previous comment. You forgot `B = A.'`. Try `B = A.'; result = reshape(B(1:end-2), [4 4 3]);` (copy and paste)

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting - thank you, sir!!

Comment: Let me know if it works so I can post it as an answer

Comment: It works! Thanks again

Comment: Great! Answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the following works:

```
B = A.'; % transpose to have the data in column-major order
B = B(1:end-8); % remove last values in linear order. Gives a column vector
result = reshape(B, [512 512 113]); % reshape to desired size
```